# android location service GPS accuracy value range

Tags: android, gps

My phone Motorola Fire Android 2.2 shows worst accuracy for GPS reading as 250 meter. This has been confirmed with 'GPS Test' program. Beyond this the GPS reading are not available, icon starts blinking ... However I hear different android phones show different worst accuracy figure. Is this true ? If yes, how can one figure out what is worst expected accuracy in program ?

Answer (score 0):

As of API level 9 (Android 2.3) you can specify the accuracy by the values in [Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_COARSE). `ACCURACY_LOW`, `ACCURACY_MEDIUM` and `ACCURACY_HIGH` give you estimated min/max values for their criteria matches.

For API <9 there may be some information if you look into Android's source code but I'm fairly sure there's nothing mentioned SDK level about it.